# Webpack doesn't recognise jsx syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have the following Webpack config:

```
... 
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            options: {
                presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { modules: false }], '@babel/preset-react'],
                plugins: [
                    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', { useBuiltIns: true }],
                    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'ignore-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'ignore-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif|pdf)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[path][name].[ext]'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
        <StaticRouter location={path} context={context}>
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I use this in my renderer:

```
const renderer = (html, path, context) => {
    const serverHtml = ReactDOM.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={path} context={context}>
            <Layout />
        </StaticRouter>
    );
    const regex = /(<div id="root">)(<\/div>)/;
    return html.replace(regex, function(original, div1, div2) {
        return div1 + serverHtml + div2;
    });
};
```

I call it here as a simple test:

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile("./src/server/html/index.html", "utf8", function(err, data) {
        const context = {};
        const html = renderer(data, req.path, context);
        console.log(html);
        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

These are my dev-dependencies (package.json):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-hot-server-middleware": "^0.6.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
```

Shouldn't the `@babel/preset-react` preset take care of it?

As a matter of fact, purely executing webpack on the config file doesn't throw any errors.
What I'm trying to do is perform hot reloading and SSR, for which I'm using the packages mentioned in package.json.

I get the error when starting the app and using the following middleware:

```
const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
    const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
    const webpackHotServerMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-server-middleware');
    const config = require('../../webpack.development.config'); //Contains both client and server webpack config

    // Webpack dev hot reload middleware
    const compiler = webpack(config);
    app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        serverSideRender: true,
        stats: {colors: true}
    }));

    app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler.compilers.find(compiler => compiler.name === 'client')));
    app.use(webpackHotServerMiddleware(compiler));

}
```

Note:
Actually, the reason why I get this error is because I should first transpile the code with Webpack. The import doesn't work because obviously the JSX syntax can't be understood by NodeJS.
This doesn't really solve my problem though. The npm package that I'm using executes webpack at runtime after the import has already happened.
So either you can come up with a way to solve this, or I guess that I won't be able to use jsx syntax...

Comment: maybe is not webpack, could you copy the file were you are using `<StaticRouter> ` component

Comment: @ramirozap Just added it :)

Comment: IIRC, React has to be in scope to trigger the jsx transpiler. Are you importing react in the file that’s throwing the error?

Comment: maybe try test: /\.(js|jsx)$/ instead of  test: /.js$/,

Comment: @rayhatfield Yes. tomen I don't use jsx files in my current demo.

Comment: I don't know much about Server Side Rendering, but I think `renderToString` is a function from `ReactDOMServer` and not from `ReactDOM`, could be that?

Comment: @ramirozap I import it as: `const ReactDOM = require("react-dom/server");` and should work. It seems to have problems with the jsx syntax. I'm hurting my brain to figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot supply both rules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleexclude) like you did here:

```
include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
exclude: /node_modules/,
```

The exclude will override the include. To have "both", you need to write it like this:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!react)/
```

You'll also need to specify your `entry` parameter to your `src/index.js`.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but it  doesn't really work for the reason I mention in the last part in my OP. Regarding  the webpack config, I did define the entry, but didn't share the entiree webpack config. But regarding  your comment about not  being able to use th rules together, that doesn't make sense to me. I want to transpile what's in the includes and leave out node_modules.